# Modify the height of a div in parallel when I drag a button

Tags: javascript

Requirements:

When I drag the button vertically upwards, the height of the yellow div must decrease.

When I drag the button vertically downwards, the height of the yellow div must increase.

Problem:

When I drag the button vertically upwards, the height of the yellow div increases.

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName ("button")[0];
//ele.onmousedown = eleMouseDown;
ele.addEventListener ("mousedown" , eleMouseDown , false);

function eleMouseDown () {
    stateMouseDown = true;
    document.addEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
}

function eleMouseMove (ev) {
    
    var pY = ev.pageY;
    
    ele.style.top = pY + "px";
  
    document.addEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
     var test= document.getElementById("mybox").clientWidth;
    test = test - pY;
 
    
    var  test2= test.toString();
    test2= test2+"px";
    document.getElementById("mybox").style.height=test2;
    
}

function eleMouseUp () {

   
    document.removeEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
    document.removeEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}
```

```css
.test{
width:150px;
height:150px;
background-color:yellow;

}
.button{
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="mybox" class="test" > test</div>

<div><button  class="button">drag me</button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

the behavior of the yellow div is the inverse of how it should behave

Could you please help correct my code?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're subtracting `pY` from `test`, when what you actually want to do is simply set `test` equal to `pY`.

Instead of `test = test - pY`, you're looking for `test = pY`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
//ele.onmousedown = eleMouseDown;
ele.addEventListener("mousedown", eleMouseDown, false);

function eleMouseDown() {
  stateMouseDown = true;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", eleMouseMove, false);
}

function eleMouseMove(ev) {
  var pY = ev.pageY;

  ele.style.top = pY + "px";

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", eleMouseUp, false);
  var test = document.getElementById("mybox").clientWidth;
  test = pY;

  var test2 = test.toString();
  test2 = test2 + "px";
  document.getElementById("mybox").style.height = test2;
}

function eleMouseUp() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", eleMouseMove, false);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", eleMouseUp, false);
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="mybox" class="test"> test</div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">drag me</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that you might want to subtract a few extra units of height to `test` to cover the height of the button. I've gone with `test = pY - 10` in the following example:

```js
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
//ele.onmousedown = eleMouseDown;
ele.addEventListener("mousedown", eleMouseDown, false);

function eleMouseDown() {
  stateMouseDown = true;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", eleMouseMove, false);
}

function eleMouseMove(ev) {
  var pY = ev.pageY;

  ele.style.top = pY + "px";

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", eleMouseUp, false);
  var test = document.getElementById("mybox").clientWidth;
  test = pY - 10;

  var test2 = test.toString();
  test2 = test2 + "px";
  document.getElementById("mybox").style.height = test2;
}

function eleMouseUp() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", eleMouseMove, false);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", eleMouseUp, false);
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="mybox" class="test"> test</div>
  <div>
    <button class="button">drag me</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!